Why useEffect called Multiple times when axios is present inside
I am just now Learning React JS, stuck with the following issue
useEffect is called Multiple Times, even when state value is passed in Dependencies. How to fix it?
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const ViewProfileUseEffect = () => {
    const [userList, setUserList] = useState([]);
    const naviagte = useNavigate();
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:4000/users").then((response) => {
            setUserList(response.data);
            console.log('I am inside useEffect');
        }).catch((error) => {
            alert("Something went wrong")
        })
    }, [userList]);
function handleProfile(id) {
        naviagte(`/profile/${id}`);
    }

    function deleteProfile(id) {
        axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/users/${id}`).then((response) => {
            console.log(`Delete Response Data ${response.data}`);
        }).catch((error) => {
            alert("Something went Wrong");
        })
    }
    return (
        <>
            <h3>View Profile</h3>
            <div className='container' style={{ backgroundColor: 'bisque', width: '500px', padding: '20px', borderRadius: '5px' }}>
                <table className='table'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope='col'>UserName</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Email ID</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {userList.map((user) => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={user.id}>
                                    <td>{user.userName}</td>
                                    <td>{user.userEmail}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={() => handleProfile(user.id)}>View Profile</button>
                                        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => deleteProfile(user.id)}>Delete Profile</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default ViewProfileUseEffect

The Output I got

"I am inside useEffect" is coming in console multiple times endlessly
How to stop it?

Take userList  out of the dependency..   First it's not a dependency, and it's different every render..

Because the effect is triggered by changes to an array that triggering it changes. What did you think would happen?

@Keith, I need it becoz I need to update the Table when a user is deleted. So when user clicks on Delete I need to update in realtime. If I give just [] as dependency after clicking on delete, the table is not updated in realtime.

You cannot update the thing in the dependency array inside useEffect without creating an infinite loop. Additionally, useEffect will run twice in development and strict mode to shake out bugs.

useList is still not the dependency.  If you want it to update on delete, one idea is store a lastDelete flag state that you update, and the  use that as a dependency...

you should not include usersList as dependency for your useEffect!
and it has a good reason.
when the component finishes rendering (the mounting phase) it will run the useEffect. so it will fetch the data and set the users.
but the usersArray has changed again and it will run the useEffect again and again..
you should remove the dependency and it will be fixed.
 useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:4000/users").then((response) => {
        setUserList(response.data);
        console.log('I am inside useEffect');
    }).catch((error) => {
        alert("Something went wrong")
    })
}, []);


Please be informed that when you're in the development environment, and your <App /> component is rendered inside a <React.StrictMode><App /><React.StrictMode>, your useEffect hook is going to run twice when you component mounts. However, this doesn't happen in the production environment. If you don't want your useEffect hook to run twice in development environment, you can remove the React.StrictMode wrapper around the <App/ > component render.
In addition, you have userList state in your useEffect dependency but the state variable has no effect on your api call. You should remove it from your dependency list otherwise, you would run into infinite loop.
I believe the above instructions should fix your issues.

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:4000/users").then((response) => {
        setUserList(response.data);
        console.log('I am inside useEffect');
    }).catch((error) => {
        alert("Something went wrong")
    })
}, [userList]);

when you fetch the data the userList is change and that makes useEffect rerun and also when it rerun the userList is also change or effected so it will be also rerun and so on ... leave the array empty,
or disable reactStrict mode from the main react file where you call the root div.
